# How to translate this deterministic finite state automata into a regular expression..

Tags: automata, regular-expressions, finite-automata

What is this Finite state automata represented as a regular expression.

[Click here for FSA image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQYFh.png)

Comment: Try generating a few legal strings first to get an idea. In particular, how many ones are in a legal string.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible regular expression is:

$R = (0|2)^*1(0|2)^*(1(0|2)^*1(0|2)^*)^*$